# ios - How to send a JSONModel object to backend using AFNetworking to a Flask backend?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I'm working on an app and I use `AFNetworking 3.0` and `JSONModel`.

For the backend I use `Flask` framework and use `Flask-RESTful` to generate apis.

Now I can send `NSDictionary` object but I wonder how to send a `JSONModel` object to the backend so that in the backend I can read it as `json` data?

Here's my code

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @"1",
                                   @"password":@"2"
                                   };
    //请求的url
    NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost:5000/test";
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];     
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];   

    [manager POST:urlString parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

And I have a `BaseEntity` which is inherited from `JSONModel`

```
#import <JSONModel/JSONModel.h>

@interface BaseEntity : JSONModel

@property (assign, nonatomic) int id;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* name;

@end
```

Comment: `[YOUR_BASE_ENTITY_INSTANCE toDictionary]`?

Comment: Yes. `toDictionary` can convert the `JSONModel` instance to a dictionary and I can send the dictionary object to my backend. It works. Do you know what are the differences between `toJSONString` and `toDictionary`? The only thing I know is that their return types differ. Under what circumstances do I use `toJSONString`? Thanks.

Comment: Could you find an answer for that? @Jinglei.Y

Answer (score 0):

You can use YYModel framework ,the url: https://github.com/ibireme/YYModel

Such as:

// Convert json to model:

User *user = [User yy_modelWithJSON:json];

// Convert model to json:

NSDictionary *json = [user yy_modelToJSONObject];